# How to wrap a program and a batch script in a standalone .exe?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, self-extracting

I'd like to wrap my own copy of Google Chrome and a batch script in a standalone application (.exe-file). Basically, what I want to achieve is for a user to double-click the application icon, and Google Chrome will start with custom parameters (ie. from command line with flags).  (Why? It's the only way to avoid SSLv3 vulnerability on Chrome).

So is this possible? Everything needs to be in one file - but it could be a self-extracting archive that would extract itself on first run (but then start normally on subsequents).

Thanks

Comment: why not run the existing chrome that they have, but with the right parameters? Maybe it's possible to unpack and run a Chrome installation without really installing it.  What parameters get around the SSL vulnerability? Specifically what vulnerability are you referring to. I heard of a recent SSL vulnerability but it's to an SSL server. It only affects people running an SSL server. So I don't see why calling chrome with certain parameters is going to help.

Comment: I would like to wrap own Chrome, to make sure it's latest version. All I really need is to bundle it somehow to make it idiot-proof - ie. one-click on an app icon. I'm thinking of just having a batch script to launch Chrome, but I'm not usually on Windows. (With OSX it's just a matter of a simple Automator script.) The flag is --ssl-version-min=tls1 btw, for SSLv3 vuln. (This is also a vulnerability client side - I believe you'll find your browser vulnerable here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html ;) Btw, I have other reasons for wanting flags - to run as an app, for example.

Comment: So you want to run said wrapper and have it extract a folder with Chrome already prepped and then put a desktop icon to start Chrome with the parameter `--ssl-version-min=tls1`? Is that it? Or do you want to have the wrapper install Chrome silently and then put the desktop icon to start Chrome with the parameter? And is that solution (desktop shortcut with parameter) enough for you?

Comment: Either is fine - but yeah, making sure it's latest Chrome and start with flags is the goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not adding the parameter to Chrome's shortcut? This can be done on the quick launch bar or on Desktop. Don't know about Metro apps.

[image]